# Any solution to schedule two campaigns with same contact email and different contact properties?

Tags: mailjet

I use MJML to send mail with mailjet and I populate the body of my mail with contact properties. My problem is if I have the same contact on both campaign, I cannot split contact properties... any suggestion to fix it ?

I think about :

- store the whole mail information as contact properties and inject in mail template body the information
- dupplicate contact properties by compaign

... no nice solutions there.

Answer (score 1):

What is the use case that you have here Cyril, as I am interested to find out. The structure is as follows, you have Contact lists populated with Contacts, which Contacts have Contact Properties. At the end you are targeting those Campaigns to Contact Lists.

One solution would be for that contact to have two different contact property, perhaps property1 and property2 and for the first Campaign to call [[data:property1]] and for the second one [[data:property2]]. But I could give a better answer here if I am bit more aware of what are you trying to achieve and what is the use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I implement a solution like this. I add a suffix to properties , it is related to campaign ID. Then on my contact properties I create new "suffixed properties" related to campaign.

Comment: That's a smart one indeed @CyrilALFARO